# Removing question marks in front of records in QGIS

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, attribute-table, expression, string

I am using QGIS 3.10.3 and noticed some question marks in one column of the attribute table. These marks are just before the numbers and represent the currency symbol.

I want to get rid of them. I tried in the open Field Calculator this code: `substr("fieldname", length("fieldname")-1)`. It deleted the question marks and the first numbers. How can I just delete the question mark?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use this expression with the [`replace()`](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/functions_list.html#replace) function:

```
replace("fieldname", '?', '')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a substring, based on regular expressions with [`regexp_substr()`](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/functions_list.html#regexp-substr) to output all charcters of the input except `?` with this expression:

```
regexp_substr ("input",'([^\\?]+)')
```

[image]